# Spring REST @RequestBody is always empty

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, put

So after I fixed the '415 media not supported' error ([415 media not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067101/ajax-request-to-spring-rest-api-415-error/34083632#34083632)), I encountered a new issue. My `RequestBody` is always empty. When I send a request via **Chrome PostMan** I always get a serialized entity back with only null values. I am using `Spring (4.2.3.RELEASE)`,`Jackson-databind (2.6.3)` and `jackson-core (2.6.3)` in my project. I am using annotation based configuration in my project (`@EnableWebMvc` to make spring automatically discover  `HTTPMessageConverters`).

---

**Other posts**

I am aware of other posts on stackoverflow, with almost the same problem. Yet they did not provide me with an answer. Also the most of the posts are for older Spring versions (pre 4.0), so some things are quite different now.

Similar posts:

[@RepsonseBody is always empty in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063392/requestbody-is-always-empty-in-spring)

[Spring's @RequestBody providing empty string on POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806724/springs-requestbody-providing-empty-string-on-post)

[Using HttpServletRequest request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467035/spring-mvc-dont-deserialize-json-request-body)

---

**Spring controller**

In my Spring `@RestController` I have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/location/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public UserLocation updateUserLocation(@PathVariable("id") int id, UserLocation user) {        
        return user;        
}
```

I am using a separate model class (`UserLocation`) for my data binding. This is because this way I have more control of the data my API sends and recieves.

---

**Databinding class (UserLocation)**

The UserLocation class consits of 3 properties with a constructor and the required getters and setters. (I could make those properties public, but I first want to fix this problem).

```
public class UserLocation {

    private Float latitude;

    private Float longitude;

    private Date lastActive;
}
```

---

**JSON body**

Via my AngularJS Ajax call (`$http.PUT`) I make a call to the spring controller with the following data:

```
 {
    "latitude": 52.899370,
    "longitude": 5.804548,
    "lastActive": 1449052628407
 }
```

---

**PostMan request**

I am developing a Cordova application, so to test requests without the need of building my application to my mobile phone, I am using **Chrome PostMan Plugin**.

I am making the following call:

`URL:` `http://server:port/app/location/update/1`

`Method:` `PUT`

`Headers:` `Content-Type: application/json`

`Body:`

```
{
    "latitude": 52.899370,
    "longitude": 5.804548,
    "timestamp": 1449052628407
}
```

---

**Request result**

With the request I get the following result:

```
{"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"lastActive":null}
```

This means that Spring does make a new instance of my `UserLocation` class, but it does not fill it with the data from the body..

---

**Spring PUT method**

When using the PUT method in a Spring controller, isn't the entity updated immediately? So that would mean that there would be no extra logic in the controller for updating the entity right? (if the entity is of course a **Hibernate/JPA** model, which can be updated).

---

***I cannot seem to figure out the problem. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?***

---

**Update**

Adding `@RequestBody` to my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/location/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public UserLocation updateUserLocation(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody UserLocation user) {        
            return user;        
}
```

Brings me back to my original question ([415 media not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067101/ajax-request-to-spring-rest-api-415-error/34083632#34083632)). Adding this throws a 415 Media not supported error I cannot seem to fix.

---

**Fixed. Solution below**

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the problem, however with PostMan  you are sending `"lattitude"` instead of `"latitude"` and `"timestamp"` instead of `"lastActive"`.

Comment: @francescoforesti, thanks for the headsup. I thought I had changed that. I'l change it in the post. (code was already up to date)

Comment: @Mr.wiseguy your problems got solved ?

Comment: @TomSebastian, Yes. In this case Driss Amri and you both gave the solution. The total solution can be found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067101/ajax-request-to-spring-rest-api-415-error/

Comment: This may be not an answer but I think it may help if you are using Lombok with IntelliJ and have this problem. For me it happen because of I'm using Lombok with @Data annotation, means getters and setters are supposed to be generated implicitly, but they were not. Lombok didn't do it job properly. I tried to add getters/setters method explicitly and it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see a @RequestBody in your Controller for the UserLocation object? Also make sure your properties have getters and setters.

```
public UserLocation updateUserLocation(@PathVariable("id") int id, UserLocation user) {
```

When doing a HTTP PUT, you WILL have to put extra logic to persist your object to the database. You will need to call your DAO or Repository to persist your object. Usually you map your incoming UserLocation object to a real JPA/Hibernate entity that you persist. This will not happen automatically.

Comment: '@RequestBody' is not nessecairy anymore since the introduction of '@RestController' (Spring 4.0). I am returning the instance of UserLocation Spring makes for me. That results in an empty JSON string (see my post). 

Thanks for the info about persisting. Then I will still need to implement that code.

Comment: As far as I know, @RequestBody is not optional. I think you are confusing it with @ResponseBody? https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html

Comment: Adding @RequestBody brings me back to my original question. This brings up a 415 media not  supported error.

Comment: Are you sending the "Content-Type: application/json" header with postman?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067101/ajax-request-to-spring-rest-api-415-error for my 415 error

Comment: Every @RequestBody bean must implement Serilizable interface.

Answer (score 5):

Problem is you missed to annotate the UserLocation parameter with `@RequestBody`

```
..updateUserLocation(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody UserLocation user)
```

Also make sure to generate `getters` and `setters` for `UserLocation` memeber variables.